# U-Boot Compile Error on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: compiling, embedded, boot-loader, arm, u-boot

I've been following this [tutorial](https://bootlin.com/doc/training/embedded-linux-4d/embedded-linux-4d-labs.pdf) on how to set-up a basic boot loader configuration on an embedded system. I've been stuck on the U-boot part owing to not being able to build it.

Downloading U-boot

```
git clone https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/u-boot.git
cd u-boot
git checkout v2018.11-stm32mp-r2.1
```

Building the software

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
make stm32mp15_basic_defconfig
make menuconfig
sudo apt install device-tree-compiler
make DEVICE_TREE=stm32mp157a-dk1
```

Upon entering `make DEVICE_TREE=stm32mp157a-dk1` the terminal shows the following error message:

```
make: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
./scripts/binutils-version.sh: line 18: arm-linux-as: command not found
  CHK     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.autoconf:77: u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

I've added both the tool chain and the U-boot folder to PATH. Also`arm-linux-gcc` pertains to `arm-training-linux-uclibcgnueabihf`.

I'm new to embedded systems and Linux in general.

I've search for solutions online. The problem seems to be that it is using x86 instead of arm (?) and installing `lib32bz1` seem to solve it. However, it does not work for me.

What may be causing this? How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the cross compiler is wrong. Check your path to the cross compiler, check if you can acces your gcc from cmd line typing `arm-linux-gcc`, wether you can acces the cross compiler or not.